# The TFS User can see all project without permission

Tags: tfs

I have two projects in my tfs as you can see

[image]

My first project have 3 users :

```
1.zandi
2.tfs
3.akbar
```

The second project has 2 users :

```
  1.zandi
  2.tfs
```

So as you can see the akbar shouldn't see the second project .But he can see and he can download it.why ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that the user `akbar`is a member of a Group which has the permission to access the second project.

You need to check if the user `akbar` has the collection level or access the second project permissions:

1. **Manage Server** (gear icon) >> Select the **Collection** which the projects belong to
2. Click the link "`Manage collection security and group membership`"
3. Switch to **Users** tab under **Security**
4. Enter the user `akbar` in search box (filter out the user)
5. Select the user `akbar` >> Check the permissions
6. Switch to **Member of** tab to check which groups the user belongs
   to
7. Check the permissions of the user Groups, make sure they do not have
   collection level permissions, Check the **Username Or Scope**, make sure the **second** project is not listed there.

Generally,make sure the user `akbar` or the nested groups which it belongs to are not a member of below groups:

- Project Collection Administrators
- Project Collection Build Service Accounts
- Project Collection Service Accounts
- Project Collection Test Service Accounts

[image]